# Getting Type error : argument of type int is not iteratable in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate through a nested dictionary. I want to display all  the values associated with the key: "city_name". This is my piece of code.

```
nested_dictionary = {"responseCode": 0,
  "responseDesc": [
    {
      "city_id": 1,
      "city_name": "Mumbai",
      "total_trips": 0
    },
    {
      "city_id": 2,
      "city_name": "Delhi",
      "total_trips": 0
    }
    ]
}
temp = "city_name"

for i in nested_dictionary.keys():
    print(i)
    if i == "responseDesc":
        x = [v[temp] for k, v in nested_dictionary.items() if temp in v]
        print("The extracted values : " + str(x))
```

Each time i try to run it throws the type error. I am not able to figure out where is the value of x becoming an integer?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[i['city_name'] for i in nested_dictionary['responseDesc']]`

Comment: @KlausD. Unless there is\can be an `i` that does not contain `'city_name'`.

Comment: @Ma0 The author of the question is free to improve the code (or the question) to cover that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access to whole dict instead of included list of cities "responseDesc"

I think you was going to get somethinkg like this:

```
nested_dictionary = {"responseCode": 0,
  "responseDesc": [
    {
      "city_id": 1,
      "city_name": "Mumbai",
      "total_trips": 0
    },
    {
      "city_id": 2,
      "city_name": "Delhi",
      "total_trips": 0
    }
    ]
}
temp = "city_name"

x = [desc[temp] for desc in nested_dictionary['responseDesc'] if temp in desc]
print("The extracted values : " + str(x))
```

Comment: this makes sense. The error was coming off of k, v being responseCode and 0, and trying to say if temp in v, and you could not do in 0

Comment: why do you need the outer for loop at all here?

Comment: Ah really, I missed the moment when copping. I have edited. Thanks

Comment: @SimfikDuke it works. Thanks.. can you please explain how this works. and why will it not consider the 'if' case ?

Comment: We skipped this:
for i in nested_dictionary.keys():
    print(i)
    if i == "responseDesc":
because only one unique key can be in dictionary

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need. You need to fetch the **value** using the key.

```
x = [v[temp] for v in nested_dictionary[i] if temp in v]
    print("The extracted values : " + str(x))
```